# Vector that has string and map types inside of it

Tags: c++

I want to make a vector that holds string types as well as map types with vectors inside of them. I just can't get it to work.

```
std::vector<std::variant<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>>> Map{
   "Cat",
   "Dog",
   "Snake",
   "Horse",
    {{"More",std::vector<std::string>{"Alig","Tiger","Lion"}}}
};
```

I get "no instance of constructor" followed by a long error.

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: The compiler can't deduce that the `{{"More"...}}` part is meant to represent the map. `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>{{"More",std::vector<std::string>{"Alig","Tiger","Lion"}}}` works, but is rather verbose. A typedef or two might help.